# Required fields for Unit Testing in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have an application form in my project and I want to write unit tests.
My code behind has required fields for server side validation to ensure the field is not blank. I need help to know if I've written this right because this is only my second day of writing unit test. please be nice i am only 13.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a title")]        
public string Title
{
    get; set;
}
```

Then in my unit test I did

```
public void TitleIsNotBlank()
{
    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(_vm.Title);
}
```

Would this check that field is not blank?

Comment: It would indeed.  Though keep in mind it bears no mind to the `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a title")]` attribute, the unit test is just directly testing the field itself.  I also don't think there's a guarantee that an empty string would exhibit the same behavior between that attribute and the `IsNotNullOrEmpty` assertion.  (Although it coincidentally may have the same behavior.)  So it might be worth testing that edge case explicitly.

Comment: I only understood half of that. You're saying that it would only test the field is not empty or null but it would not test that the error message returned is that error message. If so, I understand. Thank you

Comment: That's a correct understanding, yes.  You shouldn't really *need* to test the attribute's behavior, as that's a framework component and is generally tested by the vendor.  Depends on how much you might distrust the framework.  Unit testing at 100% coverage is a worthy goal, but in any complex system there is always (1) debate on what "100%" means and (2) diminishing returns on testing some components.  (Which means the value of testing some code doesn't always outweigh the cost of developing the tests.  Sometimes.)

Comment: yes I understand. Im trying to improve the percentage of coverage so im hoping with these many required fields it willl go up. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand that the `[Required]` attribute only decorates the property but it does NOT automatically validate it unless something calls upon its functionality.

By decorating the property, you are telling any other process that may inspect it that it should be required and what the error message should read. The MVC framework's validation, for instance, fires the validation within this attribute for you. That's when validation actually occurs.

In my opinion, this should ideally be tested at the business object level (when you actually assign the value of the model to an object and try to do something with it, like save it).

The assumption is that the attribute's validation code has been tested, so you don't need to. However, since your goal is to increase coverage, what you can do is test to make sure the field is "marked" as required by inspecting it and making sure it is decorated as such:

```
var type = typeof(YourModelClass);
var property = type.GetProperty("Title");
var attributes = (Required[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Required), false);
Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Length > 0);
```